# Running complex calculations (using python/pandas) in a Django server

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, numpy

I have developed a RESTful API using the Django-rest-framework in python. I developed the required models, serialised them, set up token authentication and all the other due diligence that goes along with it.

I also built a front-end using Angular, hosted on a different domain. I setup CORS modifications so I can access the API as required. Everything seems to be working fine.

Here is the problem. The web app I am building is a financial application that should allow the user to run some complex calculations on the server and send the results to the front-end app so they can be rendered into charts and other formats. I do not know how or where to put these calculations.

I chose Django for the back-end as I expected that python would help me run such calculations wherever required. Basically, when I call a particular api link on the server, I want to be able to retrieve data from my database, from multiple tables if required, and use the data to run some calculations using python or a library of python (pandas or numpy) and serve the results of the calculations as response to the API call.

If this is a daunting task, I at least want to be able to use the API to retrieve data from the tables to the front-end, process the data a little using JS, and send it to a python function located on the server with this processed data, and this function would run the necessary complex calculations and respond with results which would be rendered into charts / other formats.

Can anyone point me to a direction to move from here? I looked for resources online but I think I am unable to find the correct keywords to search for them. I just want a shell code kind of a thing to integrate into my current backed using which I can call some python scripts that I write to run these calculations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is about "how do I do these calculations in the restful framework for django?", but I think in this case you need to move away from that idea.

You did everything correctly but RESTful APIs serve resources -- basically your model.

A computation however is nothing like that. As I see it, you have two ways of achieving what you want:

1) Write a model that represents the results of a computation and is served using the RESTful framework, thus your computation being a resource (can work nicely if you store the results in your database as a way of caching)

2) Add a route/endpoint to your api, that is meant to serve results of that computation.

**Path 1: Computation as Resource**

Create a model, that handles the computation upon instantiation.
You could even set up an inheritance structure for computations and implement an interface for your computation models.

This way, when the resource is requested and the restful framework wants to serve this resource, the computational result will be served.

**Path 2: Custom Endpoint**

Add a route for your computation endpoints like `/myapi/v1/taxes/compute`.

In the underlying controller of this endpoint, you will load up the models you need for your computation, perform the computation, and serve the result however you like it (probably a json response).

You can still implement computations with the above mentioned inheritance structure. That way, you can instantiate the Computation object based on a parameter (in the above case `taxes`).

Does this give you an idea?

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot for explanation. It indeed gives me an idea on how to proceed, but I am not proficient enough in Python to do these. The only thing I ever used Python for was data analysis. Anyway, I will figure it out. I think I have used too much of inbuilt functions of the framework, and followed tutorials too strictly without understanding what exactly each thing means. But just to clear something up, do you think I need to revamp what I did till now completely to implement your suggestions, or can I integrate them into what exists?

Comment: And I guess this might sound naive. Currently, an API url is registered in the urls.py, and this is associated with a Viewset that exists in serializers.py. This Viewset calls a Serializer class that has a model attached to it's meta options. This model is defined in models.py. So where exactly in this process flow can I implement your suggestion of using a custom endpoint? Obviously I will have to register the endpoint in urls.py. But beyond that I only have a vague idea with very less clarity. Do you think you can help me out?

Comment: @SrujanRouthu Hey, sorry for the late reply. You are on the right track. If you look closely at the `urls.py` you can see, that when a pattern matches, a function will be called. This function can be anywhere. So if you feel like it you can create a file "`controllers.py`", add a function to it, import it in the urls.py and it will be called once you hit the right route giving you a request object!

Comment: Thanks. That clears up a lot of vagueness in my mind. So in a file called "`calculations.py`" i'll create a set of classes and functions to run my calculations. Then i'll create "`controllers.py`" as you suggested in which I will create a controller for a particular url, run some query sets to extract data from the database, run these data through some functions in "`calculations.py`", and serve the results as the response. Does this process flow makes sense? Also, will there be difficulties in converting `numpy` arrays or `pandas` dataframes into JSON objects that can be served?

Comment: I would not advise you to do your queries in the controllers. You already have database models the calculations have to be run on right? so the controller should just get the models and pass them to something that can perform the calculations. Creating json is widely supported I dont think you will run into a lot of trouble with this one but I have never tried pandas. numpy has good interfacing for iterables so it shouldnt be too hard :)

Comment: yeah, you're right. I do have models for the database. Ok, I think I understand now. I will try and see how much I can figure out. Thanks a lot. I appreciate it. :-)

Comment: What did you do in the end? Did you still use pandas?