# Serving Multiple RASA bots on Django Backend

Tags: python, django, rest, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I’m currently trying to serve multiple bots (running different models) and to allow users to interact with it on a website. I’ve had a look at the following: http://www.rasa.com/docs/nlu/http/, http://www.rasa.com/docs/core/http/ and http://www.rasa.com/docs/nlu/python/, but I’m still having trouble figuring out how it can be done.

Some of the solutions I’ve considered are either:

1. Serve the bot on a HTTP server and have my website interact with the Rasa HTTP server
2. Create the website on Django Framework or REST API, and run Rasa Core and NLU on the backend.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? And, could anyone please briefly explain how this can be done (with multiple bot models and instances running)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did a bit more searching and found these posts which partly answers my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374454/machine-learning-tensorflow-sklearn-in-django
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547102/running-complex-calculations-using-python-pandas-in-a-django-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else searching for an answer, I ended up using Flask as the server, along with Flask-SocketIO for real time communication. The server serves an API which allows clients to communicate with it via SocketIO, determines which bot to interact with, gets the response, and sends it back to the client.